# Count of result sites in google search and rivalry level of query

Tags: php, search, count

I'm working with PHP web site and I need to get count of sites for custom expression in Google search. Also I need to get rivality level [0..1] of this custom expression (query).

I've searching for something like this in Google Custom Search API but didn't find.

Thanx for helping.

Comment: Can't you just hit the actual search page (with curl or whatever) and parse the returned HTML?

Comment: Yes, but also I need to get query rivality level.

Comment: it's Competition: The number of advertisers that showed on each keyword relative to all keywords across Google. Note that this data is specific to the location and Search Network targeting that you've selected. In the "Competition" column, you can see whether the competition for a keyword is low, medium, or high. This data is from Google AdWords. Maybe this value is in AdWords API, but I do know how to find it.